# Typescript error in vue 3 / vitejs / volar project on "required" html tag

Tags: html, typescript, vue.js, vite

don't know how to fix this error on the required tag:

> (property) InputHTMLAttributes.required?: boolean | undefined Type
> 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean | undefined'.ts(2322)

```
<input required="true" v-model="email" placeholder="Email" type="text"/>
```

Comment: try binding it: `:required="true"` or just `required`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `required="true"` HTML attributes will allways ba a string.
2. `:required="true"` vue bindings will allways be JavaScript.
3. `:required="'true'"` would therefore be a string too.

You are probably looking for No. 2

Comment: :required="true"
Thank you